# Migration from Geth to Parity: Is there anything to copy/export?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-key, import, migration, parity

So, I want to migrate to gain disk space thanks to blockchain pruning (it seems that it goes from ~11.4 GiB to ~3.3 GiB) and try the difference of sync speed.

Is this already documented somewhere? (how to jump from the different ethereum implementations)

Is there something else than the private keys that might need to be migrated? If so, how to proceed?

Comment: You can run `geth export` to export the blockchain data using `geth`. But I don't know if `parity` can import the exported file though.

Comment: And the private keys?

Comment: While certainly not ideal, another way to get rid of so much storage is to `rm -rf $ETHEREUM_DATADIR/chaindata` and restart with `geth --fast`, that should reduce the disk usage significantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing special needs to be done. Private keys will be imported automatically.

On a typical machine, it will take around 1 hour to sync with the network.

Comment: They import the keys? Pretty cool.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot import/export blockchain between geth and parity. However you can import/export wallets between clients.

*To import to `geth` you can actually try the `--fast` command with geth. If it is to parity its only less than 2GB the entire blockchain.*

Comment: Do you have a source for this? Other comments/examples here say you _can_ migrate blockchain data between geth & parity

Answer (score 3):

This is documented at https://wiki.parity.io/Importing-a-Chain-from-Geth.html

In essence, you can create a fifo using `mkfifo`, and then run

```
geth export /tmp/yourfifo
```

Put that in the background, and import to parity using

```
parity import /tmp/yourfifo
```

This is for the blockchain itself, not the wallet (from my understanding).

Comment: looks like the primary question is about keys, perhaps should address that.