# geth 1.5 taking too long to sync

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain

my geth (geth-windows-amd64-1.5.5-ff07d548) is taking too long to sync. It has been two days and it is still not fully synced. Still missing about 600 000 blocks.
Ports are opened (TCP 30303, UDP 30301), using `geth.exe --cache=512 --datadir G:\Wallet\data\` and my internet connection is 6MB/s.
The G: drive is internal western digital black 2TB.
Windows 10
Edit: 1 block sync takes about 12min. (600 000x12=years)

Comment: See http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/10453/1268

Comment: I had the same exact issues. Switched the Parity and never looked back. I'm pretty sure it had to do with the spam transactions from Sept./Oct. and the subsequent Spurious Dragon hard fork. I think once you're past those, it speeds back up. Not sure what block numbers that is though.

Comment: currently I am running `geth --fast` option, seems okay for now. If I want to use Parity (`parity --geth` right?), can I set the chaindata folder like with Geth? if yes, then how?

Comment: No you can not use the same chaindata in parity, it will [import your keys automatically](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2553/87) though. However, if you run `parity --warp` you will be _warped_ to the latest block [within a few minutes](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/9991/87).